# What is the best way to pull all items with label from Jira programmatically?

Tags: label, jira

I have searched a fair bit and gotten close.
But still struggling to pull the data I want from jira's api.

the api is
https://jira.internal.company.com/rest/api/2/

I can get a reply from it.
Were functional and its behaving as it should.

My struggle is with labels.

What I hope to do is programmatically pull all items in our jira that have the tag "cloud"
and get a json response.
From there the goal will be to write that data to a sqlite3 db and store it in s3 for consumption.

I tried:

```
https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=labels%20IN%20(%22labelname%22)
```

But that just returns no values.

Comment: There's nothing wrong on it. I was about to guide you check the error code from the server as it may lead you to incorrect authentication (and as you mention in your own answer, this is the root cause).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was silly close:
The update to postman moved my Auth off of basic auth.

This does work:

```
https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=labels%20IN%20(%22labelname%22)
```